# Ruby on Rails your connection is not private

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl

I have a Ruby on Rails app. I have installed `Symantec Norton Secured SSL` and the app is running on AWS. Currently when viewing in browser the app works fine, but in mobile device like Android and IOS, there is this issues of `Your connection is not private`

[image]

[image]

The seal on the website not mentioning any issues.

Comment: Are you using some sort of anti virus on your mobile device?

Comment: Ignore my answer, for some reason I didn't read that you installed Symantec Norton Secured SSL